# Javascript: ACE editor inside a FancyBox

Tags: javascript, html, web, editor

I have an web application which displays data in text boxes/textareas (tonnes of them).
Changing this web application to use `<div>`s is really out of the question as it would cost more than the gain of implementing ACE.

I have tried to create an example which would load the ACE editor inside a FancyBox when clicking on the textarea/text box.

My example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/espenfjo/tHqGd/5/

The problem is however that it doesn't seem like the ACE javascript can find the new `this.content`.

edit: Of course.. other solutions to how to make fancy text boxes/textares with ACE would also be very welcome.

Comment: I can use something like `ace.edit($(".fancybox-inner")[0]);`. It feels extremely unclean though.. And I have not been able to write contents back to the textarea yet.

Answer (score 0):

I went by using `$(".fancybox-inner")[0]` instead of using an own `<div>` for this.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/espenfjo/tHqGd/8/

Now I can click a textarea (or whatever really), and get a fancybox with the ACE editor updating the textarea.